# iSeries Datasource Locking

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, cognos-10

I have a data source set up on my AS400 (iSeries) and when Cognos accesses it through the client access ODBC driver, it locks the files on the AS400.  Even if the report closes the files remain locked for a length of time.  This causes issues with updating the datasource, reorganizing files, clearing records, etc.  There has to be a way of forcing the ODBC driver to remove the lock when the data has been retrieved...or at the very least, monitor the time that it keeps its hold.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Cognos 10.1.0....
iSeries V7R1M0

Buck, 
Thanks for taking the time to comment....however, I assure you my iSeries is in fact running V7R1M0, and I never said that I had a record lock.  I said a file remains locked.  I'm pretty sure that my question does pose a specific scenario in which Cognos accesses the AS400 Files through the Client Access ODBC Driver, and locks the file.  Then holds the lock for an certain amount of time.  My question was if there is a way to stop Cognos from keeping that lock on the file.  I can provide error messages for random file accessing  on the iSeries after this lock has taken place, but as I was looking for a way to relieve the lock before those errors occurred, I didn't see its relevance...but I am sure I would receive a CPF3203 error telling me that it cannot allocate the object.

Comment: This seems like a fairly common problem with products which use ODBC to communicate with the IBM i. It's not clear to me what the "proper" way to handle it is, but one thing that some folks recommend is setting the ODBC handler on the i to not allow reuse of connections. That is, have ODBC threads end themselves after one use instead of the default of staying alive for (I think) 200 uses. I'm not an administrator, so I don't know the technical terms or exact steps, but maybe this jogs other people's memory.

Comment: Also, there is some debate about whether this hurts performance or is otherwise inefficient with system resources. It also feels like a "treat the symptoms, not the underlying cause" type of fix, because most likely the ODBC handling on the IBM side is "working as designed", and would not create problems if only the client software would use ODBC the way IBM expects/hopes. But whether it's IBM being too pedantic/stubborn or the client software being too sloppy, we're stuck with apparently no solutions that are both expedient and clean.

Comment: John, the situation also arises with interactive jobs using SQL to access tables.  Your program issues a CLOSE CURSOR, DB2 does a pseudo close and therefor DB2 holds a *SHRUPD lock on the table.  This is normally a 'who cares' sort of thing because ordinary read/write access to the table still works fine.  What doesn't work are things like CLRPFM which demand a *EXCL lock.  I don't see this as an ODBC or DB2 problem, it's a problem of keeping old batch processes which require CLRPFM in the process flow.

Comment: @BuckCalabro: Hmm... that would corroborate the behavior pattern we've seen. If I recall correctly, we can still do record-level access, even delete records; but can't get an exclusive lock on the table. It still *feels* like a "zombie" lock left over from the client software, because there wasn't any lock at all before the client software tried to access the table. Nice edit in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBM i 7.1 does not run on AS/400 or iSeries hardware.  This isn't a semantic nit: searching the web for ODBC and AS400 will return ancient and non-useful results.

The question doesn't include a specific error message, nor a specific scenario where that error occurs.  I'm guessing that you're seeing an object lock (not a record lock) on `CLRPFM`.  If so, the root cause is that the database manager doesn't completely close cursors; it soft closes them (sometimes called a pseudo close) for performance reasons.

If you have a non-SQL process that needs an exclusive lock on the table (like `SAVOBJ`, `CLRPFM`, `DLTF`, `RGZPFM`, etc.) then you can include an `ALCOBJ` command with the parameters set to force close any pseudo closed cursors.  `ALCOBJ OBJ((SOMSCHEMA/SOMETABLE *FILE *EXCL)) WAIT(1) CONFLICT(*RQSRLS)`

If I guessed wrong, please edit the question to show the action being taken on the IBM i side that is throwing the error, and the exact error message ID of the error.

**EDIT**: Better explain locking

Any ODBC access, any RPG record level access, any process that opens a table for input results in a lock on the table.  If the I/O request is for read-only, the lock level is *SHRRD (shared for read).  If the I/O request involved update, the lock level is *SHRUPD (shared for update).  This is normal and desirable behaviour and cannot be disabled because it happens deep in the operating system and is in the DNA of IBM i.

These object locks allow for shared access; if your Cognos process has a *SHRUPD lock on a table, then my RPG program can still open, read, write and update records in the same table, at the same time.  This is how all modern databases operate.

Typically, when questions like this arise, there is a server process that demands an exclusive (*EXCL) lock on the table.  Typical server side operations are CLRPFM, RGZPFM, SAVOBJ.  If a table is opened by Cognos with a *SHRUPD lock (WRKOBJLCK will tell you this), a server side process like CLRPFM cannot obtain a *EXCL lock and will issue a CPF3203 - Cannot allocate object for file.

The piece that sometimes gets lost is the pseudo close.  A typical ODBC process might look like this:

- ODBC connect
- Open cursor
- fetch result set
- close cursor
- ODBC disconnect

On the DB2 side, one would expect that when the 'close cursor' step occurs, the *SHRUPD lock is released.  That does not necessarily happen because DB2 performs a pseudo close, leaving the cursor in memory for the next time Cognos does the very same access (except say, with a different customer).  For most operations, this is not a problem - who needs a *EXCL lock on a table during the day when Cognos can request access at any moment?  But our legacy isn't so simple, and most of us still have server side processes that do a quick CLRPFM to clear out a batch from a work table.  And that's where the CPF3203 occurs.

Since the database manager is holding the lock (not the Cognos process, which disconnected!) we need to tell DB2 that we want to have a hard close performed before we do a CLRPFM.  The ALCOBJ CONFLICT(*RQSRLS) is how we do that.  This would need to be added in the CL program doing the CLRPFM.  Another way around this is to use SQL to clear the table.  On 7.1, we can issue SQL commands in a CL program so instead of CLRPFM TEMPFILE we can do RUNSQL 'delete from tempfile' - being SQL, it doesn't require a *EXCL lock on the table.

**EDIT**: RGZPFM

Some background on RGZPFM is probably in order.  Very old applications did not delete records in tables: they set a 'deleted record' byte that the application needed to check.  Over time, the tables accumulated increasing numbers of records tagged as deleted or inactive.  Disk was expensive, these records were superfluous, so the reorg was born.  Typically it was a two step process: copy the file to a temporary copy, then copy it back, omitting the 'deletes'.  This worked OK because the reorgs typically ran at night as part of the end of day processing, when interactive users were off the system.  An additional benefit was putting the records physically in primary key order; this increased performance for programs reading by key.

More modern applications were able to issue an actual, physical DELETE operation on the row, but that row still took up space.  Disk was still expensive, and so RGZPFM was born.  RGZPFM still needed exclusive access to the table, for the same reasons as the two-step CPYF did.  Many of these RGZPFM processes were simply inherited without considering the necessity of an actual reorg on newer (faster) hardware with much more disk.  Some applications perform a reorg because 'that's how we always did it.'

It's 2014, and the hardware is really fast and disk is quite cheap.  Tables can be created to reuse deleted records - this is the default for tables created with `CREATE TABLE`, and with very few exceptions works without a performance issue - and performance was a major reason for RGZPFM.  There is still a place for RGZPFM, and that's for use with large tables with many deleted records - a sparse table.  If you have an SQL SELECT that results in a full table scan, that's going to be a performance hit.  Generally speaking, there aren't many of those tables; if you have a multi-million row table, it's probably a history file and doesn't see a lot of DELETE activity.  But it's something to think about for those few situations where a sparse table has millions of rows AND no goot index.

Comment: is right. IBM i 7.1 is not supported on AS/400s nor iSeries; it requires at least System i hardware. **However**, the point of that is that web searches can give much more relevant results by **not** running searches with "AS400" or "iSeries" as a search term, but using "System i" or "IBM i" instead. When an older name is used, many irrelevant results cloud the returned list making it harder to narrow down. Also, the `ALCOBJ` advice is what should cause the server processes to release the locks.

Comment: 1. I apologize for my references to older hardware models, I thought you were saying I couldn't be at V7R1M0 at all.  I actually just got slapped by an IBM rep for calling it an AS400...he kept correcting me and telling me it is an iSeries....now I'm going to set him up and slap him down with the system I!

Comment: 2. I understand what you are saying about the locking.  I was just hoping someone might have an approach in Cognos Properties to destroying the connection.  We have a bunch of programs that have been floating around clearing files or reorganizing them...(which really seems like it could have been planned out a little better).  And I actually started using sql to clear them...but once I hit the rgz and didn't know of an sql command that could duplicate, I started approaching it from the Cognos side.  I think I will go back to my manager and find out exactly why he needs to do all these RZGPFMs

Comment: Appreciate the help and patience!

Comment: No need to apologise.  It's kind of a vicious cycle: until midrange professionals start using the current terminology, web searches are going to commingle 20 year old 'answers' with yesterday's answers.  So I try to encourage current usage when possible.  I edited the answer to add a bit of history on RGZPFM.  You may be able to change the tables to reuse deleted records and eliminate the RGZPFM altogether.

Comment: Ironically I got here by googling "exclusive lock as400" and this was the top hit, but I found *my* answer on the second hit, at go4as400.com